# Get All Materials from Array in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have this code in stackblitz that needs to get all materials. How can i get all the materials and not just one. The output is just one materials and not the lists? Here's my code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qssycg?file=app/app.component.ts

> JSON

```
orders =
  [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Not Available",
    "address": "Not Available",
    "city": "Not Available",
    "contact_number": "Not Available",
    "created_at": "2017-10-26 16:12:22",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-26 16:12:22",
    "materials": [
      {
        "id": 21,
        "sku": "D22D12D4",
        "name": "D-2, 2D-1, 2D-4",
        "created_at": "2017-10-26 03:03:43",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-26 03:03:43",
        "pivot": {
          "supplier_id": 1,
          "material_id": 21
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 40,
        "sku": "ACWNAIL",
        "name": "Assorted C.W. Nails",
        "created_at": "2017-10-26 03:19:54",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-26 03:23:21",
        "pivot": {
          "supplier_id": 1,
          "material_id": 40
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 49,
        "sku": "DDJENAMEL",
        "name": "Doors & Door Jambs - Enamel",
        "created_at": "2017-10-26 03:33:06",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-26 03:33:06",
        "pivot": {
          "supplier_id": 1,
          "material_id": 49
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> ts

```
patchValues() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.orders.forEach(material => {
      rows.push(this.fb.group({material_id: material.materials[0].id,material_name: material.materials[0].name, quantity: material.materials[0]}))
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not a link to code. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @EdCottrell. I just edited it

Comment: That's better; thanks. It's still pretty unclear to me what you're asking, but I'm not an Angular person, so maybe another user will understand it better.

Comment: @EdCottrell. I'm getting one material and not a list.

Comment: Well, you always index it with `[0]`, so you're always going to get only the first one in your `rows.push(...)` statement. I don't know if that's what you're referring to, but that would seem like a pretty obvious problem. That said, it's really not clear to me what you're even trying to do.

Comment: @EdCottrell. That's the problem is the [0] index. That is why is getting only the first material. I dont know how to get all materials

Comment: You need to loop over `material.materials`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to iterate to nested array and push those values to your form array. So your `patchValues` should look like this:

```ts
patchValues() {
  let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
  this.orders.forEach(material => {
    material.materials.forEach(x => {
      rows.push(this.fb.group({material_id: x.id,
                               material_name: x.name, 
                               quantity: 'there is no quantity in your data'}))
    })
  })
}
```

notice, that you don't seem to have `quantity` in your JSON. Also this solution only takes in consideration that you have only one object in your `orders` array. If you are aware that there is more, you need to also create formgroups in your formarray.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwnjjr?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Well the field is already there! I just assigned it a value 'there is no quantity in your data'. You just remove that string value....

Comment: How can i add  Validators.required in quantity field?